# Email html frameworks? (aka Bootstrap for emails)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, email, frameworks

I am looking for a list of good Email/HTML frameworks for my next web project. As far as I know, it is very difficult to make good working HTML for all platforms & browsers.

Best working solution would have following:

- List of patterns, that can be reused (say basic elements like copy, H1, H2, full-width images, tables, lists)
- CSS template engine (LESS/SASS), to style all files once
- Basic grid
- Support for mobile devices

I have found only this solution from Mailchimp: https://github.com/mailchimp/Email-Blueprints

Any other options?

**Upd.** So far found these:

- http://zurb.com/ink/
- https://github.com/rodriguezcommaj/salted
- https://github.com/mailgun/transactional-email-templates
- https://github.com/leemunroe/html-email-template

Also really good overview about sending emails here — http://www.leemunroe.com/sending-email-designers-developers/

Comment: you will end up making your own templates because if you want them to work on most of browsers and email platforms you will end up with inline styling and tables lots and lots of tables so that the Outlook can understand what you want it to show.

Answer (score 5):

You should check out mjml, which is a nice component based markup language from which you can generate email html. https://mjml.io/ You can even fork it on Github: https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml This component based approach is getting more and more wide spread.

Also, we have built a nice editor tool for creating responsive emails. You can try the editor if you click on the demo button here: http://edmdesigner.com/responsive-email-editor-for-end-users If you like it, you can register here: https://app.edmdesigner.com

Answer (score 2):

You can try this http://zurb.com/ink/

If you are adding background images, this site will help you to get that showing in outlook http://backgrounds.cm/

And here you can get another boilerplate **emailology.org**

Emails are tricky. None of those above mentioned boiler-plates are full-proof. Best option would be to test your emails.

Email testing tool > **litmus.com** or **emailonacid.com** Unfortunately they are not free.

A free email sending service to test your emails by sending to your email address (and perhaps your friends who have other devices) is **putsmail.com**

Answer (score 0):

Generally simple HTML should work quite well in todays mail clients/browsers. Avoid images and external resources, write everything needed to display the E-Mail correctly inline inside the HTML code. Like ths CSS. Avoid JavaScript, this will not work.

If you wanna use a service, MailChimp is awesome, but you also check wanna check

[sendgrid.com](http://sendgrid.com)

and

https://sendloop.com

Wich I personally both also liked. But I would prefer MailChimp in general for you.

Comment: Still far from proper framework, that I'm looking for. You can check Mailchimp knowledge base to understand, how complex is to create "simple HTML".